# i want to access full table(with column name) from sql server database in android?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout

### Hi am new to android. I want to access full table with column name from sql server database am already bind the value to column(1,2,3)to(A,B,C).i want to n number of column and rows please help me...

**This is activity:**

```
public class MainActivity1 extends Activity{
Button EXECUTAR;
EditText ValorBusca;
ListView Lista;
SimpleAdapter AD;
MainActivity ma=new MainActivity();
TableRow tr;
public  void QuerySQL(String COMANDOSQL) {
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        //String sql="select * from Activity";
        Statement statement = ma.connect.createStatement();
        //DatabaseMetaData md = ma.connect.getMetaData();
        ///rs = statement.executeQuery(COMANDOSQL);
        /// rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT  INV.ITEM_NAME,INS.QTY,INS.RATE,INV.discount,INS.[STD RATE],INS.MRP,INS.GRPCODE,INV.cname1,INV.cname2,INV.cname3,INV.cname4,INV.cname5,INV.cname6,INV.WSP,INV.TAXCODE,INS.ICODE,INV.BARCODE,INS.[EFF RATE],TAX.TaxName FROM INVITEM INV LEFT JOIN TaxMaster TAX ON TAX.TaxCode=INV.TAXCODE LEFT JOIN INVSTOCK INS ON INS.ICODE='"+ValorBusca.getText().toString()+"'");
        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ValorBusca.getText().toString()+"");


        List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
        data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();


        while(rs.next()) {
            Map<String, String> datanum =new HashMap<String, String>();
            datanum.put("A",rs.getString(1));
            datanum.put("B",rs.getString(2));
            datanum.put("c",rs.getString(3));
            data.add(datanum);  
        }

        String[] from = {"A","B","c"};
        int[] views = {R.id.txttitulo,R.id.txtconteudo,R.id.textview3};
        AD = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.modelo, from, views)
        {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.modelo, null);
                }
                TextView text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txttitulo);
                TextView text2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtconteudo);
                TextView text3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview3);

                text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                text2.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                text3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                return super.getView(position, v, parent);
            }
        };

        Lista.setAdapter(AD);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERRO",e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Enter Table Name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
    EXECUTAR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_buscar);
    ValorBusca = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_buscar);
    Lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ValorBusca.setText("");
    EXECUTAR.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            QuerySQL(null);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute(query);    
ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
```

To get the Number of columns:

```
rsmd.getColumnCount();
```

To get name of the COlumn:

```
rsmd.getColumnName(i); // WHere i is index
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this Tutorial to get the data from SQLLite Databse and insertion and etc..

Please have a look at this [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

i think this will helps you.

instead of result set and etc..